# Freezing when selecting GNOME on Xorg

Tags: gnome, xorg, 17.10, wayland

I need to use X11 instead of wayland for Zoom.

When I select "GNOME on Xorg" my laptop freezes right after I click login. I have tried selecting "Ubuntu on Xorg" and have the same result.

I can only login to the default "GNOME".

Once I login to GNOME I can lock, log in as another user, select "GNOME on Xorg", unlock and I can get back to the desktop without it freezing. BUT echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE returns wayland and not X11.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a new dell XPS 15.
GNOME 3.26.2
i7-7700HQ
Intel HD Graphics 630 / Nvidia GTX 1050
16 GB RAM
64 bit

Comment: I have this exact same issue on: HP Spectre x360 13, late 2016 model. i7-7500U, Intel HD Graphics 620 / Nvidia GTX 1050, 8GB; Any Chance you have found a solution?

Comment: I was unable to use x11 at all on 17.10. I did a fresh install and still had the same issue where choosing xorg would still use wayland. I did a fresh install of 16.04 and when I switched prime to use integrated graphics I got stuck with a login loop. Adding acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=Windows 2009 to grub fixed that. Then I was able to log in with integrated graphics enabled and x11 session. Zoom was still laggy during screen share so I installed cinnamon desktop.